# Какую библиотеку использовать для локализации веб-приложения?

Tags: javascript, локализация, web-apps

Есть веб-страница с веб-приложением, язык приложения должен зависеть от текущей локали. Какие js-библиотеки применяются для этой цели?

Вариант `{'ru':{'label1': 'A'}, 'en':{'label1': 'B'}}` не интересует.

Answer (score 1):

Локализацию целесообразнее производить на стороне сервера, это позволяет минимизировать трафик, передающийся по сети. В Ruby On Rails, например, для этого используется библиотека i18n https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n

Comment: стороны сервера нет

Answer (score 1):

Если на клиенте angular, то angular-translate.
GitHub:
https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate
Хабр:
habrahabr.ru/company/eastbanctech/blog/242455/

Если нет, то localize.js
https://github.com/coderifous/jquery-localize/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение? Добавьте минимальный пример решения в тело ответа (информация по ссылке может быть удалена в любой момент).